# What is [Summary("")] used for in discord.net?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I want to make a help command in `discord.net` and I am wondering what `[Summary("")]` does. Is it possible to get the summary of a command? Is summary in discord.net like `description:` in `discord.js-commando` ? I have searched on google and I couldn't find any results on what it does.

How would I get the summary if I wanted to make a help command and what does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Summary` attribute is used to provide some information about either classes, methods or method parameters. This essentially acts as a form of "metadata" for documenting your code and allows you to create, let's say for example, a "help" command which automatically collects all the `Summary` attributes from the command groups, the commands themselves and the input parameters for the command method.
This will automatically update the "help" command, so you don't have to do it by hand.

Some basic code to showcase the usage:

```
[Command("Help")]
public async Task Help()
{
    List<CommandInfo> commands = _commandService.Commands.ToList();
    EmbedBuilder embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder();

    foreach (CommandInfo command in commands)
    {
        // Get the command Summary attribute information
        string embedFieldText = command.Summary ?? "No description available\n";

        embedBuilder.AddField(command.Name, embedFieldText);
    }

    await ReplyAsync("Here's a list of commands and their description: ", false, embedBuilder.Build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Summary` is an attribute provided by discord.net. It doesn't technically provide a specific function, however if you are interested in creating a help command or providing additional metadata for commands and/or parameters then you can access them through the CommandService.

They can be accessed through CommandInfo, ModuleInfo or ParameterInfo. meaning that you can use the attribute on your bot's modules, commands or parameters like so:

```
[Summary("The Game Module")]
public class ManualGameManagement : ModuleBase
{
    [Command("Win", RunMode = RunMode.Sync)]
    [Summary("Increments a user's win counter")]
    public async Task WinAsync([Summary("The user")]params SocketGuildUser[] users)
    {
      //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

If you take a look at the CommandService, you could do something like inject it into a module using DependencyInjection using properties or the constructor, and then use it to access the `CommandService#Commands` or `CommandService#Modules` properties and retrieve the summary.
This also applies to the `Remarks` attribute which is similar to `Summary` and the `Alias` which accepts multiple strings and is used to have multiple names invoke a command